# Can I redeem OS X Lion on a Mac different to the intended install location?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, install

I restored my MacBook to factory settings and I bought OS X Lion because my iTunes account never had it.

However, I can't activate it because the Mac can't continue unless it has the program installed or says "you must sign in with an Apple ID that was used to purchase OS X Lion."

Can I I redeem my activation code on another Apple product that has the Mac App Store in my name? or will the program install onto that MacBook?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Since the redemption code is tied to an Apple ID and not a machine, you are free to redeem it on another Mac.